# Blender BGE: set up a counter (python)

Tags: python, game-engine

this is my scritp that spawns random objects and I want to add a counter to it:

```
def spawnObjects():

    scene.addObject(randomObject1, "empty1", 90)
    scene.addObject(randomObject2, "empty2", 90)

spawnObjects()

print ("Spawned Objects are:", randomObject1, randomObject2)
```

So the script adds the objects and prints:

**Spawned Objects are:, NameObject1, NameObject2**

etc.

So far so good. But how can I get python to print:

Spawned Objects **0001 are**:, NameObject1, NameObject2

Spawned Objects **0002 are**:, NameObject1, NameObject2

Spawned Objects **0003 are**:, NameObject1, NameObject2

Spawned Objects **0004 are**:, NameObject1, NameObject2

etc.

etc.

Till infinity?

I suppose one needs a counter using "while" loop but I'm still not able to accomplish it the way I described it here.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add integer property to the object running this script and keep incrementing this property :

```
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()

def spawnObjects():

    scene.addObject(randomObject1, "empty1", 90)
    scene.addObject(randomObject2, "empty2", 90)

spawnObjects()
own['counter'] += 1 # this is the property that keeps count
print ("Spawned Objects %d are:"%own['counter'], randomObject1, randomObject2)
```

you can add a loop to spawn multiple objects at the same time,
you don't use a local variable ( defined inside the script )  because it get reset every execution of the script so you'll lose the count ,unless that is what you want.

Comment: This works great! Thanks for the explenation an the hint with the properties. Thats what I needed.